# Почему не работает запрос в QSqlTableModel?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5

Хочу оббежать таблицу с моделью QSqlTableModel, все сделал как в книге Шлее, но получаю id = 0, lin = "", domen = "":

```
for(int nRow = 0; nRow < rowsTable; ++nRow) {
    QSqlRecord rec = model->record(nRow);
    int id = rec.value("id").toInt();
    QString lin = rec.value("link").toString();
    QString domen = rec.value("domen").toString();
}
```

Может это из-за того что я переопределенный QSqlTableModel использовал, еще не пробовал?

Comment: Не вижу здесь запроса.

Answer (score 1):

может до обращения к модели надо сделать какой нибудь запрос?
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html#details

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506841/how-to-get-the-value-in-qsqltablemodel